# Best way to access and store files on kubernetes cluster without cloud resources

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

I need to persist files of different formats and sizes on a Kubernetes cluster volume and access them simultaneously by several applications.

I know there are cloud resources like Azure Files that can help with this issue of simultaneous access to the same storage volume. However, one of my project requirements is not to use cloud resources to persist files.

So what can be the best way to persist files and access them simultaneously without using any cloud resources?

Answer (score 0):

We are currently running NFS which is behaving really good and it is pretty straight forward to set it up, however there are several options to get non cloud storages:

**cephfs**

A cephfs volume allows an existing CephFS volume to be mounted into your Pod. Unlike emptyDir, which is erased when a pod is removed, the contents of a cephfs volume are preserved and the volume is merely unmounted. This means that a cephfs volume can be pre-populated with data, and that data can be shared between pods. The cephfs volume can be mounted by multiple writers simultaneously.

[More info](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/volumes/cephfs/)

**iscsi (does not meet your needs!)**

An iscsi volume allows an existing iSCSI (SCSI over IP) volume to be mounted into your Pod. Unlike emptyDir, which is erased when a Pod is removed, the contents of an iscsi volume are preserved and the volume is merely unmounted. This means that an iscsi volume can be pre-populated with data, and that data can be shared between pods.

A feature of iSCSI is that it can be mounted as read-only by multiple consumers simultaneously. This means that you can pre-populate a volume with your dataset and then serve it in parallel from as many Pods as you need. Unfortunately, iSCSI volumes can only be mounted by a single consumer in read-write mode. Simultaneous writers are not allowed.

[More info](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/volumes/iscsi)

**nfs**

An nfs volume allows an existing NFS (Network File System) share to be mounted into a Pod. Unlike emptyDir, which is erased when a Pod is removed, the contents of an nfs volume are preserved and the volume is merely unmounted. This means that an NFS volume can be pre-populated with data, and that data can be shared between pods. NFS can be mounted by multiple writers simultaneously.

[More info](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/staging/volumes/nfs)

[Further info-Kubernetes Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/)

Comment: Thank you for your help. And how can I access such a volume within a .NET application, for example? Is there any link that can help me with this process of accessing the volume and persisting the files from one of my applications?

Comment: i would suggest to check NFS, it consists on a few installation steps, here.  https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/staging/volumes/nfs btw i have further info if needed.  i will update

Comment: I checked that link but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. I wanted some examples of how within my .NET application I can persist files to volume. Do you have any useful links for this?

Comment: when you refer to .net i guess you are talking about your .net "dockerized" application or deployed in Kubernetes. not directly from the .net code. Am i correct ?

Comment: I also refer to the code. How do I access an nfs server based persistent volume with c# codes?
Sorry if I'm not being clear, I'm starting my studies in kubernetes and containers.